# Can't drop more than one clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The following code will only let me drag and drop ONE clone onto a droppable area. When I try and drop another clone on the droppable area it disappears. I am able to drag it however.

```
        $(".shape").draggable({
                        helper: 'clone',
                    });

                $("#wrapper").droppable({
                    accept: '.shape',
                    drop: function(event, ui) 
                    {
                        $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone());
                        $("#wrapper .shape").addClass("item");
                        $(".item").removeClass("ui-draggable shape");
                        $(".item").draggable();
                    }
                });
```

Following the comments from people and the jfiddle provided below, it appears as though this snippet of code is working in a typical setup, however, I am using this in combination with Phonegap and more specifically on an Android device.

I know this is more specific and harder to replicate for other people, but for some reason it will not allow me to drag another clone onto the wrapper still.

Here is my entire code, if someone can spot something, i'd really appreciate it!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.1.0.js"></script>
            <script src="jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
            <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ff.css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

                // Wait for PhoneGap to load
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

                // PhoneGap is ready
                function onDeviceReady() {

                var mouseEventTypes = {
                        touchstart : "mousedown",
                        touchmove : "mousemove",
                        touchend : "mouseup"
                        };

                        for (originalType in mouseEventTypes) {
                        document.addEventListener(originalType, function(originalEvent) {

                            event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                            touch = originalEvent.changedTouches[0];
                            event.initMouseEvent(mouseEventTypes[originalEvent.type], true, true,
                                    window, 0, touch.screenX, touch.screenY, touch.clientX,
                                    touch.clientY, touch.ctrlKey, touch.altKey, touch.shiftKey,
                                    touch.metaKey, 0, null);
                            originalEvent.target.dispatchEvent(event); 
                            originalEvent.preventDefault();
                                });
                            }

                    $(".shape").draggable({
                            helper: 'clone',
                        });

                    $("#wrapper").droppable({
                        accept: '.shape',
                        drop: function(event, ui) 
                        {
                            $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone());
                            $("#wrapper .shape").addClass("item");
                            $(".item").removeClass("ui-draggable shape");
                            $(".item").draggable();
                        }
                    });

                    $(".show").live('touchstart', function() {

     if ($("#openCloseIdentifier").is(":hidden")) {
            $("#slider").animate({ 
                marginLeft: "-150px"
                }, 500 );
            $("#openCloseIdentifier").show();

        } else {
            $("#slider").animate({ 
                marginLeft: "0px"
                }, 1000 );
       $("#openCloseIdentifier").hide();
    }
                    });


                    }//onDeviceReady

            </script>
    </head>
        <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="navWrap">
                <div id="openCloseIdentifier"></div>
                <div id="slider">
                 <div id="sliderContent">
                    <img class="shape" src="images/150x150.gif" />
                </div>
                <div id="openCloseWrap">
                    <a href="#" class="topMenuAction" id="topMenuImage">
                        <img src="images/show.gif" class="show" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: not seeing it: http://jsfiddle.net/7Fa35/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

I had the shape being cloned nester in the wrapper div. That won't work.

Took it out and it works!